# CSS for Google Docs-like comments on text

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm building a system to highlight text and provide information about specific words, currently with React. I'd like to show the extra information in a box off to the side of the highlighted text. It would be like a comment on text in Google Docs. The challenge is to create boxes that "gracefully" stack and don't overlap with each other. I don't really know what to call these and haven't had any success searching for previous work on this problem. Would anyone be able to point towards relevant CSS or (even better) React components that are able to do this? Or even just what these are called?

Below is an example of the comment blocks (from a [blog](https://medium.com/denovers/google-docs-like-inline-commenting-with-draftjs-rich-text-editor-part-1-8fbf922929f7)). My question is how to make the comment boxes move flexibly to "stack" and not overlap, and basically line up as closely to the text that they're related too. I'm not asking for working code, just a point in the right direction if possible.

[image: Example of comments on top of text]

Comment: Quite interesting problem. Have you tried reverse eng their solution? I would probably start there. If you don't find anything out there, you'll need to create it.

Comment: Unfortunately the blog I link to actually only shows that animation and doesn't have an implementation to dig into. And Google's code is way to obfuscated to reverse engineer from.

Answer (score 3):

We just released a react solution for this here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sidenotes

Would love feedback! It doesn't do any of the commenting, just the placement UI and the inline references in react.

[image: Example commenting placement]